# Proving that, for $l$, $m$, $n$ odd integers, $\sqrt{l^2-4mn}$ is never rational

Tags: number-theory, conic-sections

So the question I was solving was:

Prove that if $l$,$m$ & $n$ are odd then the line $lx+my+n=0$ will never intersect the parabola $y=x^2$ at a rational point.

> I tried to solve the question and arrived at the condition that for this to be true $\sqrt{l^2-4mn}$ should never be rational. How do I prove this?

Comment: @Anguepa But then $l$ isn't odd.

Comment: You re right sorry. The square root of a natural number can only be an integer or irrational. Try to prove that the expression inside the square root can never be a perfect square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $l^2-4mn$ would have to be an odd square, i.e. $1$ more than a multiple of $8$ just like $l^2$, $mn$ would be even, a contradiction.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The system of equations
$$\begin{cases} my + lx + n = 0 \\ y = x^2 \end{cases}$$
Can be simplified as
$$mx^2 + lx + n = 0$$

As the right hand side is divisible by 2, the left hand side must be too.

But
$$mx^2 + lx + n \equiv x^2 + x + 1 \equiv x + x + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$ as $m,l,n$ are odd.